# can i restore a deleted answer in ask ubuntu

Tags: support

I have accidentally deleted my own answer is it possible to regain the same question. is there any way which I can follow and get back the same answer

Answer (score 1):

Your deleted answers should still be visible to you. If it was a recent deletion, it will still be on your profile page (look for a link to “recently deleted posts”, I think). If it wasn’t recent, there’ll be no link to it from your profile, but you’ll still be able to see your deleted answer if you go directly to the question page. Once there, read your answer, edit if necessary, then look for an “undelete” button. If you don’t find one, simply flag the answer for moderator attention and write a note explaining that the deletion was unintentional and requesting undeletion.